# Windows batch copy a file to all subfolders with dynamic naming

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file foo.txt in a folder with many subfolders with folder names:

```
\15611_Ants
\12866_Boats
\13898_Cats
...
```

I would like to copy foo.txt to each subfolder matching #####_NAME, renaming it to "##### foo.txt" in each folder. So I would have:

```
foo.txt -> \15611_Ants\15611 foo.txt
foo.txt -> \12866_Boats\12866 foo.txt
foo.txt -> \13898_Cats\13898 foo.txt
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that with the following code snippet:

```
for %%F in ("\full\path\to\file\foo.txt") do (
  for /D %%D in ("\full\path\to\folder\containing\subfolders\?????_*") do (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=_" %%N in ("%%~nD") do (
      copy "%%~fF" "%%~fD\%%N %%~nxF"
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: The used directory name pattern `?????_*` says: five valid characters, followed by an underscore, followed by zero or more valid characters; it does not validate whether or not the first part is a 5-digit number; however, if this needs to be checked, please let me know.

Comment: This worked perfectly with no modifications necessary. Thanks!

Comment: One more wrinkle - this script will overwrite any "##### foo.txt" files already in the folders, despite there being no /y switch in the copy command. How do I prevent overwriting existing files?

Comment: Have you tried it with the `/-Y` option? this enforces `copy` to ask you whether or not to overwrite if a file already exists; if you do not want any prompts, you could prefix the `copy` command with: `if not exist "%%~fD\%%N %%~nxF" `;